# R: gWidgets: gdf: a rather strange behaviour

Tags: r

I've constructed a gdf object (Group.mtcars) and I want the user **not to be able** to insert any additional row. For this, I add a handler so that when the user adds a row it is instantly deleted.

```
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
library(RGtk2)
library(gWidgets)
library(gWidgetsRGtk2)

Group.mtcars <- gdf(mtcars, container=TRUE)

addHandlerChanged(Group.mtcars, handler = function(h,...){
   # some info to be printed
   print("out of the 'if conditon'")
   IaminRow <- svalue(Group.mtcars, index=TRUE)
   print(IaminRow)

   # the condition
   if (IaminRow > nrow(mtcars)){
      # delete additional row
      Group.mtcars[,] <<- Group.mtcars[-IaminRow,]
      # go to the first row
      svalue(Group.mtcars, index=TRUE) <- 1
      # some additional info  
      print("into the 'if condition'")
      IaminRow <- svalue(Group.mtcars, index=TRUE)
      print(IaminRow)
   }
})
```

1. The first strange behaviour comes from the fact that there is an attempt for the handler to be executed once more when it shouldn't. I receive a message for this:

   > Error in handler(h, ...) : attempt to apply non-function
2. The second strange behaviour comes from the fact that the handler is not functional when we are in the first record. The first printed info is as follows:

   [1] "out of the 'if condition'"
   [1] 2

Comment: Yes, there are some errors here. I'll have to look. In the gWidgets2RGtk2 setup you could likely avoid having to remove added rows by subclassing the GDf class and modifying the method insert_row.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Since you are correcting gdf, I noticed that it is too heavy in its response compared for example with the edit(dataframe). It does not remind at all a spreadsheet behaviour, if that is the purpose. Anyway, overall its a great job you are doing !!!